# Print array element with False value

Tags: python

In python, how can I print the elements with False value?
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

height = [1.65, 1.75, 1.71, 1.72, 1.69, 1.68, 1.67, 1.70]
weight = [60, 65, 88, 59, 78, 77, 79, 72]

# Calculate and print all the BMIs
bmi = np.array(weight) / np.array(height)
print("The values of all BMIs:", bmi)

# Create an array with BMI status (True/False) less than 40
true_false_bmi = np.array(bmi) < 40

# Print out the whole true_false_bmi array as True/False
print("Status of all BMIs (Criteria -> Less than 40):", true_false_bmi)

# Print out BMIs less than 40
print("BMIs LESS than 40:", bmi[true_false_bmi])
```

Upto this it is working fine.
Now I want to print the BMIs above 40. I have tried with the following codes and it is not working:

```
# Print out BMIs of all baseball players whose BMI is above 40 i.e., False elements of the true_false_bmi array.
print("BMIs ABOVE 40:", bmi[!true_false_bmi])
print("BMIs ABOVE 40:", bmi[not true_false_bmi])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `~` operator for negation in `numpy`.

```
print("BMIs ABOVE 40:", bmi[~true_false_bmi])
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `where`:

```
print(bmi[np.where(bmi < 40)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehensions in this case. Pretty easy solution, i guess...

```
false_bmi = [not value for value in true_false_bmi]
print(bmi[false_bmi])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use filter:

```
print(filter(lambda x: x>40, bmi))
```

Edit:

or if it is a numpy array, you can just

```
print(bmi[bmi>40])
```

Comment: The code with "filter" is not working, showing an error at some memory reference. The second code is working, thanks.